# HttpRequestResponse reloading to same page in django 2.0.3

Tags: python, django

1.I am trying to develop a simple blog using django 2.0.3. in the view.py when i was trying to redirect to page from edit.html or create.html it is redirecting to it self when i was  giving the url manually it is still loading to same page i don't know why.

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from posts.models import Post
from posts.forms import PostForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse
def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {"title":"Create Blog","form":form}
    return render(request,"create.html",context)

def post_detail(request,id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id) 
    context = {
    "title": instance.title,
    "instance":instance
    }
    return render(request,"detail.html",context)


def post_update(request,id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None,instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request,"Saved")
        HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
    "title": "Edit Blog",
    "instance":instance,
    "form":form
    }
    return render(request,"edit.html",context)


def post_delete(request):
    context = {"title":"Delete"}
    return HttpResponse("<h1>delete</h1>")

def post_list(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    context = {
    "title":"List",
    "object_list":queryset
    }
    return render(request,"index.html",context)
```

2.this my urls.py

## urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
from . import views
app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$',views.post_list,name="list"),
    re_path(r'^create/$',views.post_create,name="create"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.post_detail,name="detail"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$',views.post_update,name="update"),
    re_path(r'^delete$',views.post_delete),



]
```

3.this my models.py

## model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id":self.id})
```

Comment: you have missed `return` statement.
`return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())`